# Proving two sigma algebras coincide

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(S, \mathcal{S})$ be a measurable space and $\Omega= \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} S$, let $X_i:\Omega \to S$ be the "coordinates" and $\theta_n$ the shift operators on $\Omega$: $w=(x_0,x_1,...) \mapsto (x_n,x_{n+1},...)$. Finally let $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(X_n,  n\geq 0)$ and $ \mathcal{G}_n=\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$. How would you prove that $\mathcal{G}_n=\theta_n^{-1}(\mathcal{A})$? I am puzzled because it seems to me that the antiimage of an element of $\mathcal{A}$ could very well be in $\mathcal{A}$ and not in $\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},...)$. This claim is in the context of canonical Markov Chains, Ionescu-Tulcea theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known (see, e.g. math.stackexchange.com/questions/7881) that
$$f^{-1}(\sigma(C))=\sigma(f^{-1}(C))$$
and that $A$ is generated by cylinder sets $\mathcal{B}$.

Hence $\theta_n^{-1}(\mathcal{A}) = \theta_n^{-1} (\sigma(\mathcal{B})) = \sigma(\theta_n^{-1} (\mathcal{B})) = \sigma( \mathcal{\tilde{B}}) = \mathcal{G}_n $,

where $\tilde{B}$ are cylinder sets, that generate $\mathcal{G}_n$.

Addition:
elements of $\mathcal{B}$ have the next form: $F_{t_1, \ldots, t_N, D_1, \ldots, D_N} = \{(y_0, y_1, \ldots): y_{t_1} \in D_1, y_{t_2} \in D_2, \ldots, y_{t_N} \in D_N \}$, where $D_i$ are Borel sets of real line and $t_i \ge 0$.

Elements of $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}$ have the next form: $\tilde{F}_{s_1, \ldots, s_N, D_1, \ldots, D_N} = \{(y_0, y_1, \ldots): y_{s_1} \in D_1, y_{s_2} \in D_2, \ldots, y_{s_N} \in D_N \}$, where $D_i$ are Borel sets of real line and $s_i \ge n$.

Thus $\theta_n^{-1} (\mathcal{B}) = \mathcal{\tilde{B}}$ because $$\theta_n^{-1} (\mathcal{B}) =  \theta_n^{-1} ( \{ F_{t_1, \ldots, t_n, D_1, \ldots, D_N}\}) = \{ \theta_n^{-1} (F_{t_1, \ldots, t_N, D_1, \ldots, D_N}) \} = \{ \tilde{F}_{t_1+n, \ldots, t_N+n, D_1, \ldots, D_N} \} = \mathcal{\tilde{B}}.$$

Addition2: $$\theta_n^{-1} ( {F}_{t_1, \ldots, t_N, D_1, \ldots, D_N} ) = \{ (y_0, y_1, \ldots) : \theta_n (y_0, y_1, \ldots) \in {F}_{t_1, \ldots, t_N, D_1, \ldots, D_N}  \}$$
$$= \{ (y_0, y_1, \ldots) :  (y_n, y_{n+1}, \ldots)  \in {F}_{t_1, \ldots, t_N, D_1, \ldots, D_N}  \} = $$
$$ = \{ (y_0, y_1, \ldots) :  y_{n+t_1} \in D_1, y_{n+t_2} \in D_2, \ldots  \}  = \tilde{F}_{t_1+n, \ldots, t_N+n, D_1, \ldots, D_N}.$$

Comment: Thanks but since this is not really an exercise, I would prefer a more elementary approach that doesn't use the fact you quote and could perhaps be more intuitive. If that answer doesn't come, I will accept yours. In any case I don't understand why if $\mathcal{\tilde{B}}$ generate $\mathcal{G}_n$ then $\theta_n^{-1} (\mathcal{B}) \subseteq \mathcal{\tilde{B}}$

Comment: @Karl, I made an addition. The fact that $f^{-1}$ and $\sigma$ commute is intuitive, because $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(A)$, $f^{-1}(\cup A_i) = \cup f^{-1}( A_i)$ and so on.

Comment: The $B_i$ on the left hand side are the $D_i$ on the right hand side I imagine...

Comment: @Karl, yes, it was a typo.

Comment: OK, now I don't see why  $\{\theta_n^{-1} (F_{t_1, \ldots, t_N, D_1, \ldots, D_N}) \} = \{ \tilde{F}_{t_1+N, \ldots, t_N+N, D_1, \ldots, D_N} \}$ which is the crucial problem for me.

Comment: @Karl, I made an addition. Proof by definition. Is there any questions?

Comment: One more thing that escaped me from before: you introduce $(...,y_i,...)$ but then use $y_{t_i}$. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Karl, I will give an example. Put $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ - any $3$-dimensional point. Then condition $y_1 \in (2, 3), y_3 \in (5,7)$ gives "infinite parallelepiped", because 
there are no restrictions on $y_2$.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but there are some things that confuse me, my $X_i$ take value in a measurable space $S$, not in $\mathbb{R}$. Are you assuming $S=\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity?

Comment: @Karl, it's true that it may be useful for simplicity. But I just forgot that $X_n$ are not usual random variables) In general case, of course, we should take $D_i$, which are measurable in $S$. Is there any questions?